# How to mock a library in node_modules?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to write a test for code that uses node-forge. For some reason, the test hangs when I call `forge.md.sha256.create();`:

```
  import forge from "node-forge";

  const privateKey = "foo";
  const storagePin = "bar";

  const md = forge.md.sha256.create();
  md.update(privateKey + storagePin);

  const metadataKey = md.digest().toHex();
```

As a workaround, I am trying to mock the implementation of that method so that it just returns a hardcoded string:

```
import forge from "node-forge";
jest.mock("node-forge");

forge.mockImplementation(() => {
  return {
    md: {
      sha256: {
        create: () => {
          return {
            update: () => {},
            digest: () => {
              toHex: () => "foobar";
            }
          };
        }
      }
    }
  };
});


// tests
```

However, my tests keep failing:

```
TypeError: _nodeForge2.default.mockImplementation is not a function

  at Object.<anonymous> (src/redux/epics/authentication-epic.test.js:20:27)
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
  at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:46:16)
  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)
```

The weird thing is, this strategy works perfectly fine when I try to mock my own files.

What is the proper way of mocking a 3rd party library?

Comment: Try mocking first, then importing the module. `jest.mock("node-forge")` followed by `import forge from "node-forge"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

did you try like this? More about this [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmock-docs-en-jest-object-jestmockmodulename-factory-options-with-the-module-factory-parameter).

```
jest.mock('node-forge', () => ({
  md: {
    sha256: {
      create: () => ({
        update: () => {},
        digest: () => ({
          toHex: () => 'foobar'
        }),
      }),
    },
  },
}));
```

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors sorry, what do you mean? I updated the answer, with correct syntax, I had few brackets missing.

Answer (score 1):

The `default` export isn't a function so `Jest` auto-mocking doesn't replace the default export with a mock function...

...but the `default` export **is** an object.

From [Exploring ES6](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_in-es6-imports-are-live-read-only-views-on-exported-values):

> ...while you can’t change the values of imports, you can change the objects that they are referring to.

So you can just set the `md` property on the object to your mock:

```js
import forge from 'node-forge';
jest.mock('node-forge');

const toHex = jest.fn(() => 'foobar');
const digest = jest.fn(() => ({ toHex }));
const update = jest.fn();

forge.md = {  // <= set the md property to your mock
  sha256: {
    create: jest.fn(() => ({
      update,
      digest
    }))
  }
};

test('code uses the mock', () => {
  require('./path to your code');  // <= the mock will be used in the required code
  expect(forge.md.sha256.create).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
  expect(update).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foobar');  // Success!
  expect(digest).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
  expect(toHex).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success
});
```